# jquery show the first div who has a specific span

Tags: jquery

I have several `div`s, some `div`s have a `span` with the same ID.

```
<div class="starthidden">
```

some text

```
</div>
<div class="starthidden">
  <span id="Gruppo01001">second text</span>
</div>
```

I want to show the first `div` which contains a `span` with a given ID.
I tried with:

```
 $("div:has(span#Gruppo01001").first().show();
```

But that does not seem to work.

Comment: You cannot have same IDs. That's not valid HTML or valid structure.

Comment: tyou need `firts` method `$("div span#Gruppo01001:first").show();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. IDs are unique. You should use `class` instead of IDs
2. Use `:first` to get the first `span`
3. Use `.parent()` with `show()` the show relevant `div`. You need to use `parent()` because your primary div has been given a class of `starthidden`.

Below is the updated code:

```js
$("div span.Gruppo01001:first").parent().show();
```

```css
.starthidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="starthidden">
  <span class="Gruppo01001">some text</span>
</div>

<div class="starthidden">
  <span class="Gruppo01001">second text</span>
</div>
```